# VBA Loop to Extract data from Excel into Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have already spent too many hours looking for the right answer and every which way I try it doesn't work the way I want it to.

I receive the "Application or Object defined error" referencing the Excel file when I run the following. It compiles just fine, so I am not sure where I went wrong. I need it to pull data from two different places on an Excel sheet, place them in specific defined labels in a Word doc, save it with custom name and continue to do so until the end of the list in Excel. Data begins in A1 and B1 respectively.

```
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oWB As Object
Dim exWb As String
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim bStartExcel As Boolean
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim fcount As Long
Dim iRow As Integer

exWb = "C:\Documents\Waivers_needed_0926_Take2.xlsx"

On Error Resume Next
'If Excel running use it
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'If Excel isn't running then start it
bStartExcel = True
  Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo Err_Handler
'Open the workbook
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=exWb)

'Process the worksheet
Set oSheet = oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
For iRow = 1 to 100

    With oSheet.Cells(iRow, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Amt_Paid.Caption = .Value
    End With

    With oSheet.Cells(iRow, 1)
        ActiveDocument.Payee.Caption = .Value
    End With

'Save Word Document with new name
fcount = fcount + 1
    With ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Documents\Waivers\" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & "_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & "_" & fcount & ".doc"
    End With
Next iRow

Exit Sub
```

Comment: You already made a reference to the workbook when you set `oWB`, so you do not need to reference it again on line `Set oSheet = oXL.ActiveWorkbook`, just use `Set oSheet = oWB.Worksheets(4)`. But the big question is why are you using late binding?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.  I still receive the Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Excel doesn't support a column zero - so `oSheet.Cells(iRow, 0)` is going to cause problems.  Use either `oSheet.Cells(iRow, 1)` or `oSheet.Cells(iRow, "A")`.  But I can't see why that isn't handled by the `On Error GoTo Err_Handler`.

Comment: Note:  Making people guess as to where your code is crashing is not a good idea.  It would be much more efficient if you include in the question an indication of **which** line is causing the error.

Comment: @YowE3K, thank you for the input and will test your suggestions. As for the line indication, I specifically stated above it compiles just fine. There was no indicator as to which line it was.  The error appears after I  click the button to run.

Comment: When it crashes, and shows the "Application or Object defined error" message, click the "Debug" button and see which line it crashed on.  (It will usually be highlighted in yellow.)

Comment: YowE3K, thank you for the suggestion. It fixed my loop issue.